# I can't ssh to my instance, Connection refused

Tags: oracle, cloud

I can't ssh to my oracle instance I get `Connection refused` although the instance status is "running".

So I scanned it with nmap and I found out that the port 22 is closed, to find out later that all 65535 ports are closed.So I go to what they call Ingress Rules to find that 22 tcp port is open with many others so I don't know what happen. I tried to connect it with rustdesk and it tell that the machine is offline, keep in mind that in the oracle cloud dashboard shows that the instance is running.
Did the reboot button to many times and still nothing, the little troubleshoot button that they have shows that the machine is fine. [image] all of this started after installing some tools and `sudo reboot`.
before you suggest any thing remember, I can't ssh to it.